# Compare one row date with another and decide remark - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timeserieschart

I am trying to fill in remarks based on whether the StartTime of a row lies in between the StartTime and EndTime of previous rows or not.
For eg. StartTime of 126 lies in between StartTime and EndTime of 125, thus the remarks states the same. Any idea, how can i achieve this using pandas?

| Number | StartTime | EndTime | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-03-17 0:01:13 | 2022-03-17 0:17:29 |  |
| 124 | 2022-03-17 8:26:09 | 2022-03-17 9:10:54 |  |
| 125 | 2022-03-17 16:56:08 | 2022-03-17 17:18:49 |  |
| 126 | 2022-03-17 17:00:12 | 2022-03-17 20:24:33 | interval of 125 |
| 127 | 2022-03-18 3:41:13 | 2022-03-18 3:58:16 |  |
| 128 | 2022-03-18 3:50:12 | 2022-03-18 22:56:46 | interval of 127 |
| 129 | 2022-03-18 3:55:12 | 2022-03-19 6:55:22 | interval of 127 |